# camera plugin can not added to config.xml

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera

when I added Cordova camera plugin to my project
everything works fine, but when I added :

import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

in app.module

I run the project and all white screen.

and I found there is no plugin added to config.xml

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx'`
instead of `import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';`